# How to access properties of GridView Templete Field in Web Forms

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, webforms

I have **.NET** project on **WebForms** and **GridView** in it. GridView is populated with data from my DB. The DB has column named **password** but on GridView this column is set to **Visible="False"**. When i click command button Edit all boxes are ready to be filled with new data, but column password is **invisible**.

My question is: when i click edit, **how to (or can i) make column with passwords visible and ready for filling** text box with new passwords, but also i don't want to show other password of course. Summary can i access somehow properties of this **TempleteField/ItemTemplete** ?

Comment: Yes you can do this with help of [GridView RowCommand Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to set the `Visible="false"` property. Just trick the GridView to hide a column in normal display mode and show the column when in edit mode.

Assuming `Password` Column is the third column, Handle the [**`RowDataBound`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of GridView to hide this Column:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // Just return in case GridView is rendering in Edit Mode
            if (GridView1.EditIndex >= 0)
                return;

            // In case GridView is rendering in Normal state
            // Hide the Columns you don't want to display
            if ((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal ||
                 e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate) &&
            ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || 
              e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header))
            {
                // Hide the Password Column
                e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

In case you use TemplateField for your Password Column, you can hide it by using the DataBound event of GridView as:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (GridView1.EditIndex >= 0)
            return;
       GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;            
}
```

Now when the GridView goes to Edit Mode ( on click of Edit Button etc..) it will display the `Password` column in Edit Mode.

Comment: It will fit perfectly, but i don't understand something. Okay it wont show password's column cells when it render in normal mode, but when i'm in edit mode i doesn't show them too. How to fix this when i click edit button to show them (cells) ? I'm grateful to you :) Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you removed the property: Visible="false"   from your GridView markup ?? here you will be hiding column  programmatically only as you see above. Also is your Password Column a BoundField or TemplateField ?

Comment: My password column is TempleteField, and yes i remove property: Visible=false here is how it looks

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID ="lblPassword" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

And in the code behind is the method that you told me.

Comment: Since you are using TemplateField, use the  Second Method shown: GridView1_DataBound

Comment: I walked through it with debugger several times. It will work but the problem is when i click on edit mode and event args e change from -1 to row index the column stay invisible. I think i may be good idea to set the column visibility to true when i'm in edit mode. Thanks for that you spent some time for me.

Comment: This should not happen...but ok... try seeting Column's visibility to true as well. We can debug later why column is always invisible...